# xpath in htmlunit to access button

Tags: xpath, htmlunit

I am trying to access the button in the following form using htmlunit. 
Since the button does not have a name I guess I have to use xPath in order to address it. 
I tried to access it over the class field by writing

```
page.getByXPath("//input[@class='btn small  ']");
```

but unfortunately this does not work.

Does anybody have an idea how to access it?

```
<form id="login_form" class="login" action="/login" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="" id="page_url_p"/> <input type="hidden" name="dest"
 value="" id="page_url_p"/> <label>Email or
Username</label> <input id="user"
                        class="user" type="text" name="username" value=""/>
<script>$('user').focus();</script>

<label>Password</label> <input id="pass" class="pass" 
type="password" name="password"
                               value="" maxlength="256"/> <a class="forgot" href="http://www.mypage.com">Forgot your
password?</a>

<p id="" class="btn small  " style="" onmousedown="util.toggleClass(this, 
'active')" onmouseup="util.toggleClass(this, 'active')"
   onmouseover="util.toggleClass(this, 'hover')" 
onmouseout="util.toggleClass(this, 
'hover')"><a href="#" id="" class="" style="" onclick="$('login_form').submit();
return false;" target="" tabindex="">Sign in</a></p></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
page.getByXPath("//p[@class='btn small']/a");
```

Try the above. The class is on a `p` tag and the button is an `a` tag

Another alternative is `page.getByXPath("//a[text()='Sign in']");`